# SSRS 2008 use multiple tabs in Excel

Tags: excel, reporting-services

Can SSRS 2008 support multiple tabs in excel?  I read that it is not available until 2012 however I was wondering if there is some sort of workaround out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reports rendered to excel will contain a new tab per hard page break. For example, if you define a group for a table and set a page break after each group then the page breaks will be spread out on separate tabs in excel.

Comment: Here is a visual example which helped me to accomplish this task:  http://bi-harpreetsingh.blogspot.com/2011/10/exporting-report-to-multiple-excel.html